# Hints to compute the limit $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+2}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

Should I use the squeeze theorem to compute this limit: 
$\lim_{x\to 0+} \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+2}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}\right) = 0$?

Comment: Maybe multiply by conjugate over itself first.

Comment: This is certainly not necessary, but I would almost automatically let $t=1/x$ before continuing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

As usual:
$$\sqrt a-\sqrt b=\frac{a-b}{\sqrt a+\sqrt b}.$$
Then factorize the denominator by $\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}$ and conclude.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that I must multiply by the conjugate fraction (as suggested by @Foobaz John and @coffeemath) not only the conjugate :). My final answer was $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}} = \frac{2\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{2x+1}+\sqrt{1}} = \frac{0}{2} = 0$

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+2}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}$.

If you multiply $f(x)$ by $\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}}=1$, then value of f(x) will remain then same. And you will get $\lim_{x\to0+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0+}\frac{(\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+2}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}})(\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}})}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}}=\lim_{x\to0+}\frac{\frac{1}{x}+2-\frac{1}{x}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}}=\lim_{x\to0+}\frac{2}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}}=0$

Comment: You transcribed the problem incorrectly.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Is it fixed now?

Comment: The term in the second radical should be $\frac{1}{x}$ rather than $x$.  Judging by the numerator you obtained after multiplying by the conjugate, it looks like you had that in mind, even if you did not write it.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I did have that in mind. I think it's fixed now. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by $$\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}}$$ to get 
$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}}$$ and consider the limit as $x$ goes to the zero from the right of this expression (what happens to $1/x$).

Answer (score 0):

Another way  to squeeze: For $x>0$ and $k>0 $ we have $$0<\sqrt {1/x+k} -\sqrt {1/x}<\sqrt {1/x+k+x k^2/4}-\sqrt {1/x}=$$ $$=\sqrt{\left(\sqrt {1/x}+(k/2)\sqrt x \right)^2}-\sqrt {1/x}=$$ $$=\left(\sqrt {1/x}+(k/2)\sqrt x\right)-\sqrt {1/x}=(k/2)\sqrt x $$ and observe that $(k/2)\sqrt x \to 0$  as $x \to 0^+$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's follow the suggestion that Andre Nicolas made in the comments.

Let $t = 1/x$.  Then $t \to +\infty$ as $x \to 0^+$.  Hence,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 0^+} \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{x} + 2} - \frac{1}{x}\right) & = \lim_{t \to \infty} (\sqrt{t + 2} - \sqrt{t})\\
& = \lim_{t \to \infty} (\sqrt{t + 2} - \sqrt{t}) \cdot \frac{\sqrt{t + 2} + \sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{t + 2} + \sqrt{t}}\\
& = \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{t + 2 - t}{\sqrt{t + 2} + \sqrt{t}}\\
& = \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{2}{\sqrt{t + 2} + \sqrt{t}}\\
& = 0
\end{align*}